# Get the inserted data in the database

Tags: php, sql, database

I create a customers database through XAMPP software. I create the database named "cce" through localhost/phpmyadmin and table "customers" with five fields id, name, phone, location, notes.

I want to store customers data through index.php then I want to retrieve all customers data.

I face this error when I try to insert customers data:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'cce' in C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php on line 5
>   ERROR: Could not connect. Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'cce'

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far ?